# Tests for Likert scale in spss

Tags: likert

This is my first time working with a Likert scale and I need help with choosing a proper test in SPSS.
I have a Likert statements and want to see if there differences (and if yes what were the differences between them) based on age (18-25) and 25-30) and gender (women, men, other, rather not say). What would be the best test for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single item as your dependent variable, then a good place to start would be ordinal logistic regression with that item as your DV and the other variables as IVs.

If you have multiple Likert items and are adding them up (or combining them some other way) then please amend your answer.

I see you put the likert tag. You could also browse the items under that tag.